# How to detect Realm app user has been deleted?

Tags: swift, realm

app.currentUser.delete deletes the Realm app user from the server side. However, it seems on other logged-in devices, and the data upload is still working with no auth error.

On other logged-in devices, re-launching the app would detect that the user has been deleted. I also tried to use isLoggedIn but for authenticated devices, it seems always stays “true”.

```
RealmApp.shared.currentUser?.isLoggedIn
```

How to detect Realm app user has been deleted on other existing logged-in devices?

Comment: Note that `isLoggedIn` is a local-only indicator; is the user logged into the app, regardless of the apps online status and ignores actual current authentication status.

Answer (score 1):

User presence is a challenge with Realm; it doesn’t have a baked in user presence system.

While you can monitor when a user is Online or Offline by setting a flag or var when they log in or log out (for example) - there’s no way to monitor in-between or unexpected changes of presence or deletion.

For example, a user logs in - the app can set a var (synched with the server) to ‘Online’ that other devices are observing so their UI can be updated. Whenever that flag changes, other devices or users of the app will know about it.

But what if the app crashes, the user d/c’s for whatever reason or the user force-quits the app. That var is now “Stuck” to the on position and other devices would never know they were offline.

For this use case, you can add an observer to a object in Realm that stores user status and sync's with the server. If the user logs out on one of the devices they are logged into for example, the other devices could be notified of that change. If the user is deleted, a "is deleted" flag could be set which notifies other devices or users of that change.

Expanding on that a bit - Deleting a user could trigger a server side function to then followup with perhaps removing all of their data, cleaning up references or notifying other devices of that event.